# How is the class related to derivability?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Good evening to everyone. I have a question where they require me to find the derivability. After I read the answer sheet I saw that the function has the class $ C^1 $. How is the class related to derivability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function $f$ is said to be in $\mathcal{C}^1$ if and only if $f$ is differentiable and $f'$ is continuous.

More generally, one let $\mathcal{C}^0$ be the set of continuous function and if $k$ is an integer greater than $1$, $f$ is in $\mathcal{C}^k$ if and only if $f$ is differentiable and $f'\in\mathcal{C}^{k-1}$. One last definition, if for all $k$, $f$ is $\mathcal{C}^k$, one say that $f$ is $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$.